# senao NUB-8301 driver

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, drivers

Does anyone know if out there is a driver for senao NUB-8301 on win7. I searched everywhere and couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find, many users have had success on Windows 7 using [this driver](http://www.opendrivers.com/driver/238901/atheros-zd1211-wireless-network-driver-2.0.0.127-windows-vista-free-download.html) for Windows Vista.